# Is there an "OR" filter on uBlock Origin?

Tags: adblock, ublock-origin

I have these two rules:

```
// case1
##body:has(button[aria-label="違反報告"]) div[class*=__ReactionCounter]
##body:has(button[aria-label="違反報告"]) div[class*=__ItemReactionCounter]
```

But this set of rules is redundant, I'd prefer "or" thing if possible.

So, I tried the following:

```
// case2
##body:has(button[aria-label="違反報告"]) div[class*=__ReactionCounter],div[class*=__ItemReactionCounter]
```

But this actually doesn't block the elements like the above one. This one can be expanded like this:

```
// case3
##body:has(button[aria-label="違反報告"]) div[class*=__ReactionCounter]
##div[class*=__ItemReactionCounter]
```

This is not what I want.

Note: The page you can actually test the rules detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11271989336

So, is it possible to use "OR" (do they have?) or something to correctly implement the rule (the case2)? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem. You can use the `:is()` CSS selector.

[Selector list - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Selector_list)

So in the above case, you can use `:is()` like this to create a selector list to group them.

```
##body:has(button[aria-label="違反報告"]) :is(div[class*=__ReactionCounter], div[class*=__ItemReactionCounter])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is an OR filter, but there is dynamic filtering.

More information can be found here: [Dynamic filtering: quick guide](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Dynamic-filtering:-quick-guide)